# Accessing all elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I'm learning javascript and to practice traversing the DOM I have created a method that returns an array of parent elements based on the 'nodeName'.  I have done this so that I could select all of a certain element (that is a parent of another) and style them or change them, etc.

```
Element.prototype.specificParent = function(nodeName1) {
    nodeName1 = nodeName1.toUpperCase();
    var x = this;
    var matches = [];
    var allParents = [];

    while(x.parentNode !== null) {
        allParents.push(x.parentNode);
        x = x.parentNode;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < allParents.length; i++) {
        if(allParents[i].nodeName === nodeName1) {
            matches.push(allParents[i]);
        }
    }

    return matches;

}
```

This, kind of, has my desired effect.  However, to access all the elements in the returned array I would need to use something like a for loop, because I can only access the elements like this:

```
var parents = document.getElementById("startHere").specificParent("div"); //gets all parent div elements and returns the array  

//I can then style them individually:
parents[0].style.background = "black";
parents[1].style.background = "black";
//etc, etc, etc

//or I could use a for loop to style them all:
for(i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
    parents[i].style.background = "black";
}
```

What I want to do is this:

```
var parents = document.getElementById("startHere").specificParent("div");
parents.style.background = "black"; //changing all the elements in the array
```

Is there a way to change the "specificParent" method so that it allows this?

This may seem like a pointless exercise but I am learning!

Thanks

Comment: No, you are doing to have to use a method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I thought that was the answer but like I said, I am only learning, what do you mean by I will have to use a method?  i.e. I thought I was using a Method?!?!

Comment: `parents.forEach(parent => parent.style.background = "black")`  [documentation of array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Have you used a library like jQuery? Look at their CSS method.

Comment: You could return an object instead of the element arrays which contains methods to help you do what you want, those methods would have access to the array as withing the same scope, but you would then need a method to return the array too if needed. Look into the jQuery code base as they do that on a larger scale but the principles are roughly the same.

Comment: @GillesC Thanks for the response.  I have seen some of the jQuery source code but my current understand/knowledge of javascript is far too inferior.  Thanks for your comments, I think I will have to look much further into objects and methods, etc.  I just came across this while learning about traversing the DOM using just javascript.  The function I did was initially for this purpose but then I started wandering how to use this to style elements, etc.  Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to use [arrays API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
If you can use ES6, it would look like so:

```
parents.forEach(parent => parent.style.background = "black")
```

In ES5 slightly less clear:

```
parents.forEach(function(parent) { parent.style.background = "black"; })
```

---

Based on your comments you can do this:

```
Element.prototype.specificParent = function(nodeName1) {
    nodeName1 = nodeName1.toUpperCase();
    var x = this;
    var matches = [];
    var allParents = [];

    while(x.parentNode !== null) {
        allParents.push(x.parentNode);
        x = x.parentNode;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < allParents.length; i++) {
        if(allParents[i].nodeName === nodeName1) {
            matches.push(allParents[i]);
        }
    }

    function setStyle(styleKey, styleValue) {
        matches.forEach(function(parent) { parent.style[styleKey]= styleValue; });
    }

    return {
        elements : matches,
        setStyle : setStyle
    };
}
```

And use it like so:

```
var parents = document.getElementById("startHere").specificParent("div");
parents.setStyle("background", "black");
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I think what I was trying to achieve is much more complex than I had initially thought and much beyond my current capabilities.  I appreciate this answer but I was wanted to change the function rather than changing how to access the elements once the function returned it's array.  If that makes sense?!

Comment: I know what you mean. Essentially if you have an array of elements, you will have to iterate over all the elements you want to change. Wether you use a for loop (as in your example) or arrays API (like in my answer) depends on personal preference, but you will need to do one or another. You can use JQuery or some other libraries, but in the background they will iterate that array for you...

Comment: That's right, that's what I was trying to get at.  Within the function, I wanted to be able to iterate over the elements so that what was returned was something that could then be styled, etc.  Therefore I could repeatedly use the simple one line function and that would do the hard work for me, rather than having to re-type the loop (whichever way I chose to) every time I was wanting to style numerous elements together.   I appreciate this probably isn't possible, not simply anyway (hence the complicated{to me} jQuery).  Thanks for your input.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you an example of how you can do this without jQuery. Again, you iterate over elements, just in a different place.